# Triangle/Flipped pyramid with text boxes inside with TiKZ possible?

Tags: tikz-pgf, smartdiagram

I need to draw a graphic similar to this one. I tried messing around with tikz and pyramid shapes. When I rotate the pyramid, the text also rotates. I can't get the text like in the example and me too I'm starting to rotate! Please help me! Thank U! 
[image: Flipped pyramid graphic with text, table like...]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Draw a triangle (that are three points in TikZ and three lines between them) and then draw some vertical lines. The rest are nodes with a fixed width (distance between the lines).

Answer (score 1):

In principle, this can be done without packages.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \draw (0,0) -- (9,4) -- (9,-4) -- cycle;
 \foreach \X in {1,...,5} {
 \draw[dashed] ({9*\X/6},{4*\X/6}) -- ({9*\X/6},{-4*\X/6});
 }
 \draw ({9*(1/2)/6},0) circle (1pt);
 \node[text width={(7/6)*1cm},anchor=west] at ({9*(2/6)/6},0) {text};
 \node[text width={(7/6)*1cm},anchor=west] at ({9*(1+1/6)/6},0) {text text text};
 \node[text width={(7/6)*1cm},anchor=west] at ({9*(2+1/6)/6},0) {text text text};
 \node[text width={(7/6)*1cm},anchor=west] at ({9*(3+1/6)/6},0) {text text text};
 \node[text width={(7/6)*1cm},anchor=west] at ({9*(4+1/6)/6},0) {text text text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Proposition form simpler code : `\foreach \X in {1,...,5} \draw[dashed,scale=\X] (9/6,4/6) -- (9/6,-4/6);`.

Comment: @Kpym Well, of course, but is that shorter? In any case, one has to decide where to put the texts, which are in general different, and then compute the coordinates. But yes, I agree, there are many different options to do this here, and it depends on your preference which you find more elegant. I am certainly not claiming that the above is particularly elegant.

Comment: It is shorter ;) And you could even use `\foreach[count=\i] \t in {text,text text text,text text text,text text text,text text text} \path[scale=\i] (9/6,0) node[align=center,text width={(7/6)*1cm},anchor=east] {\t};` for the text placement.

Comment: @Kpym Sure, I agree, but when writing this answer I decided against that because this might be confusing for newcomers. There are many options such as drawing a rectangle with vertical splits and transforming it to a triangle. This would even be more confusing. I really appreciate your comments, but so far I have not gotten any feedback from the OP where the journey should go.

Comment: I know I have this flaw of always wanting to make the code as short as possible... which is not very educational. But it amuses me;)

Comment: @Kpym Yes, your codes also amuse me ;-) (More seriously, I'm learning a lot from them.) And there always tons of nice possibilities, and I guess it wouldn't hurt if you added your preferred choice here. Or both of us might save the time for more challenging questions.